# How to get JSON data from string variable in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json

```
{"features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[43.9075888632345,39.5410827982141],[43.9072923576627,39.5407692922427],[43.9070921336948,39.5405093525187],[43.906856401821,39.5402965882992],[43.9066291860298,39.5401742759428],[43.9064319803254,39.5401484540191],[43.9065181219529,39.5402838501285],[43.9066942609979,39.5405172920263],[43.9066503905753,39.5406621287682],[43.9065838779526,39.5408287916261],[43.9067755329389,39.5409986936949],[43.9071501248081,39.5411817901501],[43.9074409065243,39.5413833897095],[43.9076678059399,39.5415032206895],[43.9078429924457,39.5416138288897],[43.9078678260103,39.5415108105989],[43.9078313663027,39.5413314258037],[43.9075888632345,39.5410827982141]]]]},"properties":{"ParselNo":"1","SayfaNo":"10","Alan":"6.511,21","Mevkii":"Köy arkası","Nitelik":"Tarla","CiltNo":"1","Ada":"106","Il":"Ağrı","Ilce":"Doğubeyazıt","Pafta":"I51-c-2","Mahalle":"Alıntepe"}}],"type":"FeatureCollection","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG:4326"}}}
```

I need get JSON type from this string variable. I need get "coordinates" title value by JSON type in jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just parse it with JSON.parse(jsonString); to an object, and then you can access its fields.